# Qt - QImage is there a method to paste Qimage into another Qimage?

Tags: qt, qimage

I am looking for a way to simply paste some `Qimage` into bigger one, starting with some given `(x,y)`. Now, I am copying pixel by pixel all `Qimage`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, use a [QPainter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qpainter.html) to paint into a QPaintDevice, QImage is a QPaintDevice, so it works.

Answer (score 37):

```
QImage srcImage = QImage(100, 100);
QImage destImage = QImage(200, 200);
QPoint destPos = QPoint(25, 25);  // The location to draw the source image within the dest

srcImage.fill(Qt::red);
destImage.fill(Qt::white);

QPainter painter(&destImage);
painter.drawImage(destPos, srcImage);
painter.end();
```