# ways of copying an image into a rotated rectangle opencv c++

Tags: c++, copy, rectangles, roi

I work on Win7 x64, with openCV and Visual Studio 2010, programming in c++.
I want copying an image (call it **image**) to a rectangular area of another image (call it **RR_image**). This area, however, is rotated.

here is **image**:

[image]

and here is **RR_image**:
[image]
(as you see, I've already rotated first image)

I would copy first image in red rectangle.

How many and what ways are there to do this?

I know about ROI and: `img1.copyTo(img2.rowRange(...), img2.colRange(...));`

Thanks!

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786072/is-it-possible-to-copy-a-rotated-image-into-a-rotatedrect-roi-of-another-image-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that **OpenCV doesn't support transparency** in images, which is what you need to accomplish that task in an easy way.

So, one way to do it is to write a custom function/method to iterate over the rotated (source) image copying the pixels to the destination image, while ignoring the background pixels (a specific shade of gray, for instance). This approach is very limited, though.

**EDIT:**

OpenGL can certainly do the job, but it brings a complexity that you probably don't want on your hands right know. Fortunately there are other alternatives like [ImakeMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), which provides a C++ API through [ImageMagick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) and it can certainly handle transparent images. Take a look at [A Gentle Introduction to Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf).

The [QImage](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qimage.html) class from Qt can [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602482/176769) do this as well.

Comment: I read on Internet that OpenCV does not support transparency.. too bad!

So should I look for other libraries to copy an image to another and have transparency? like OpenGL?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll search a solution with QT or ImakeMagick!
 But, Suppose that I solve transparency problem, then how can I copy my image in the red rectangule? I cannot use Roi, right?

Comment: You will have to use Qt or ImageMagick to do the copying itself, that's the point. After the copy has been done, then you can convert the resulting data back to a `cv::Mat`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with Qt library and OpenCV.

Here how:

Given **image** and **RR_image** in order to copy the former into the latter, I used this code:

```
QPainter painter(&RR_image);
painter.drawImage( (float)p1.x(),(float)p2.y(), image);
```

**RR_image** and **image** must be a QImage object, so I have to covert them from Mat to QImage with this code:

```
cvtColor(image, image,CV_BGR2RGB);
QImage image= QImage((uchar*) image.data, image.cols, image.rows, image.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

The result is:
[image]

Hope this will help someone!